# Rails 4.1.14.2 => 4.2.7.1 values are converted to string on string fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

Rails 4.1.14.2

```
my_model.my_string_attr = { a: 1 }
my_model.my_string_attr # returns { a: 1 } (as a hash)
```

Rails 4.2.7.1

```
my_model.my_string_attr = { a: 1 }
my_model.my_string_attr # returns "{ a: 1 }" (as a string)
```

`my_string_attr` is of type `string` in the DB.

How can I store a hash/openstruct value at my_model.my_string_attr using Rails 4.2.7.1?

I couldn't find this change in the 4.2.7.1 changelog, it was probably changed in some version between (4.1.14.2, 4.2.7.1).

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to marshal and unmarshal ruby object: `JSON`, `YAML` or binary serialization with `Marshal`:

Marshal example:

```
2.2.5 :012 > hash = { a: 1 }
 => {:a=>1} 
2.2.5 :013 > s = Marshal.dump(hash)
 => "\x04\b{\x06:\x06ai\x06" 
2.2.5 :014 > Marshal.load(s)
 => {:a=>1}
```

For the other aproaches you might check http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/ or other resources.

You might also want to check the serialization API of ActiveRecord. You can specify coders / decoders for attributes, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: I think that doesn't solve my problem. I need to temporarily store (without needing to save to the DB) a hash value in an attribute which is configured as a string on the DB.

Comment: ok, well this sounds rather odd to me, might be a hint to reconsider your abstraction here